# After you create some subtitles for a video in Blender, would it be possible to extract those subtitles in an SRT file?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

After you made a video with subtitles on blender, would it be possible to extract those subtitles in a separate SRT so for example if you want to upload the video on Youtube instead of having the subtitles embedded in the video, you could have them on the Youtube window. In order, to avoid creating again the subtitles manually on Youtube itself, an extracted SRT file from Blender would be very handy. Do you think there is such possibility? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the subtitles here:

[image]

Comment: oh so simple.. nice thank you very much!!